# Definition and practical meaning of @SessionScoped

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf

I would like to understand the full meaning of the `@SessionScoped` annotation in a JSF ManagedBean.

I guess it is related to the **http session**, but still, it's not very clear to me when it *starts*, when it *ends* and if it can be *interrupted*.

- If I leave a browser open, without activity, during 2 hours.  Is the session still open?
- Is a session shared across browser tabs
- Does a session behave identical in say Firefox, IE or Safari?
- ...

Comment: JSF runs on top of Servlet API. JSF session is indeed backed by HttpSession. I think it's time to learn Servlet API as well. You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909) helpful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. no, the session times-out if there is no activity
2. yes, the session is shared across browser tabs
3. yes, the session is a server-side notion mainly, browsers only send a cookie to identify

The session starts when the user requests the first page.

The `@PostConstruct` method of session scoped beans (if exists) is invoked when you first access a page that references that bean (I'm not entirely sure in this, though)

The session ends when you call `session.invalidate()` or when it times-out (the timeout period if configurable in `web.xml`). Then the `@PreDestroy` method (if exists) is invoked.

Comment: In fact, here you have the javadoc:
http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html

Comment: Was looking for information on when @SessionScoped bean instances are created. Indeed, you're right. They're not created automatically when a session starts, but when they're first referenced by a page or injected in a lower scope bean that is used by a page. Thought my tests were wrong but you're assumption is some kind of confirmation.